# What are essential components for serializing in java?

Tags: java, serialization

Assume the following interface in project A

```
interface Business extends Serializable{//project A
 void do_work();
}
```

and here we have a class in project B which has implemented the interface

```
class LocalBusiness implements Business{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 0xF109BAC00L;
 void do_work(){
  System.out.print("Hi there\n");
 }
}
```

then I'm going to marshal(serialize) an instance of `LocalBusiness` at a certain of state.

My question is, I want to unmarshal it in project C, so does project C needs(classpath) the actual implementation of `Business` interface?

Comment: yes, it does.  java does not send along the class implementation.

Comment: When you deserialize you do something like:

YourObjectType obj = (YourObjectType) objectInputSteam.readObject();
So you will have to import all declaration for your object type. Otherwise there will be no way to tell how to deserialize.

Comment: @Luke No, you don't have to do it like that. You can refer to it by interface alone. So that is not the reason.

Comment: @Robin I am not sure if I know what do you mean. Can you give an example ?

Comment: @Luke Assuming the code in the question, `Business obj = (Business) objectInputSteam.readObject();` Also you don't have to refer to it by interface, you could even refer to everything as an Object, theoretically.

Comment: @Robin yeah of course but he wants to deserialize it in a different project so either by an interface or by a concrete object type he will need that information as an import statement since it is not saved during serialization. He can deserialize using the Object type but why anyone would want to do that ? So just to be more specific. What I mean is that serialization is not storing any structural information only state.

Comment: @Luke the question asks only whether the implementation class is needed, not the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The `ObjectOutputStream` does not contain any class bytecode for the objects written into it.

However, if you use *RMI* to invoke methods on another machine, you can use dynamic class loading, which lets one machine load code from the other - or even a third machine.

Comment: many thanks buddy, is it possible to unmarshal an object where has marshaled by class version 1 to class version 2? and assume both classes has a same serial version uid.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should. The class name of the run-time type is serialized by the default serialization mechanism. This class name is used to determine the run-time type on deserialization. If Java can't find the class with the received name (and serialVersionUID) it'll throw an exception. Try, and you'll see.

On a side note: your interface extends `Serializable`. This is considered bad practice in most circumstances.

Comment: can you give an example when having interface extending Serializable can harm you ?

Comment: @Luke The idea is that you shouldn't impose serializability on implementors unless you have a good reason to. I can think of situations where this is the case, but it should be a conscious choice. "No, unless" would be the heuristic I'd go with. (I know this is not a real example, as you asked. Hope it's still useful.)

Comment: Ok and the idea of not 'imposing serializability on implementors' is because it is not always clear that you need to take care of all the filds that you can't serialize in an implementor or some other reason ?